# Status of page, for tests to check

Tags: http, url, web

I'm writing tests for my python code and need to find a web page that returns status code grater then 307, if someone knows pages like that, plz link them. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also wanted this some time back but couldn't fine , however some of my test I used below linked for below HTTP error codes. Basically these are some rest api calls. you can try it.

HTTP error code 401 if you call

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/r

HTTP error 400 gives if you call

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/